# accessing configuration parameters using ODM Decision Center API

Tags: ibm-odm

If I create a custom configuration parameter using Decision Center > Configure > Installation Settings Wizard > Step 5: Set Configuration Parameters > New ... custom parameter, how can I access that custom parameter key/value using the Decision Center API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Custom parameters can be accessed using the following approach:

```
ManagerBean managerBean= ManagerBean.getInstance();
IlrSession session = managerBean.getSession();
String value = IlrSettings.getGlobalSetting(session, "key");
```